# Apache Camel Bindy is not workign on Linux machine while same thingis working on windows

Tags: java, linux, apache-camel

I am using Apache camel bindy to parse fix message. I am able to run this on a Windows machine but on a Linux machine I am getting following error

```
The pair separator property of the annotaon @Message must be specified
```

Following is the my fix message

```
package com.fm.fixconnector.seb;

import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.annotation.KeyValuePairField;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.annotation.Message;

import com.fm.fixconnector.domain.AbstractMarketData;

@Message(pairSeparator = "\\u0001",keyValuePairSeparator = "=" , type = "FIX", version = "4.3")
public class QuoteData implements AbstractMarketData {

    @KeyValuePairField(tag = 131)
    private String quoteId;

    private double price;

    @KeyValuePairField(tag = 132)
    private double bidPrice;

    @KeyValuePairField(tag = 133)
    private double offerPrice;

    @KeyValuePairField(tag = 54)
    private String priceType;

    @KeyValuePairField(tag = 15)
    private String currency;

    @KeyValuePairField(tag = 55)
    private String symbol;

    @KeyValuePairField(tag = 38)
    private int quantity;

    public double getPrice() {
        if ("1".equalsIgnoreCase(priceType))
            return getOfferPrice();
        else
            return getBidPrice();
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getBidPrice() {
        return bidPrice;
    }

    public void setBidPrice(double bidPrice) {
        this.bidPrice = bidPrice;
    }

    public double getOfferPrice() {
        return offerPrice;
    }

    public void setOfferPrice(double offerPrice) {
        this.offerPrice = offerPrice;
    }

    public String getPriceType() {
        return priceType;
    }

    public void setPriceType(String priceType) {
        this.priceType = priceType;
    }

    public String getQuoteId() {
        return quoteId;
    }

    public void setQuoteId(String quoteId) {
        this.quoteId = quoteId;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("MarketData [");
        if (getPrice() != 0) {
            builder.append("price=");
            builder.append(getPrice());
            builder.append(", ");
        }
        if (bidPrice != 0) {
            builder.append("bid price=");
            builder.append(bidPrice);
            builder.append(", ");
        }
        if (offerPrice != 0) {
            builder.append("offer price=");
            builder.append(offerPrice);
            builder.append(", ");
        }
        if (quoteId != null) {
            builder.append("quoteId=");
            builder.append(quoteId);
            builder.append(", ");
        }
        if (priceType != null) {
            builder.append("priceType=");
            builder.append(priceType);
        }
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Following is the context defined for this

```
 <unmarshal ref="bindyDataformatSEBPrice">
                            <bindy type="KeyValue" classType="com.fm.fixconnector.seb.QuoteData" locale="en-us"/>
                        </unmarshal>
```

Please Help me since I am struggling for this from last two days and still no success. Any help would be really appreciated. I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: what version of camel-bindy are you using?

Comment: This is probably due to windows and linux running different character sets. You should make sure that they are both using UTF8 or ASCII or whatever as long as they are the same. If you cant change the OS character set you can specify which encoding the JVM must use. This will also be an option.